# Take custom attribute instead of val() with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="size">
    <option custAttr="0" value="0" disabled selected>Value ↓</option>
    <option custAttr="10" value="10">AAA (10)</option>
    <option custAttr="20" value="20">BBB (20)</option>
    <option custAttr="30" value="30">CCC (30)</option>
</select>

<label class="result"></label>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').on('change', function() {
        $('.result').text(
            $('select[name=size]').val()
        );
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually the script takes the content from `value=""`. Is there a way that the script takes the code from my custom attribute `custAttr=""`?

Comment: Take a look at `.attr()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly note that creating your own attributes will mean your HTML is invalid which can have unexpected effects. Use `data-*` attributes to store your own data. From there you can use `option:selected` to get the required data value. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    $('.result').text($('select[name=size] option:selected').data('cust-attr'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="size">
  <option data-cust-attr="0" value="0" disabled selected>Value ↓</option>
  <option data-cust-attr="10" value="10">AAA (10)</option>
  <option data-cust-attr="20" value="20">BBB (20)</option>
  <option data-cust-attr="30" value="30">CCC (30)</option>
</select>

<label class="result"></label>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working. I have to wait 5 minutes to accept.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Still a small question: Do you know how to replace dot by comma. E.g. `123,45` instead of `123.45`.

Comment: Yep, `.replace(/,/g, '.')`

Comment: Sorry for have to ask again, but: where to add this? I tried some ways, but it didn't work.

Comment: It depends entirely on where and how you're using the value. It may be worth asking another question about it

Comment: I mean the value I'm getting like this: `$('.result').text($('select[name=size] option:selected').data('cust-attr'));` and printing like this: `<label class="result"></label>` with the code above. E.g. I've `data-cust-attr="45.21"`

Comment: In that case reverse what I gave you earlier: `.replace(/\./g, ',')`

Comment: You need to call `replace()` on the `data()` value, not the `text()`. Eg. `....data('cust-attr').replace(/\./g, ','));`

Comment: I already tried it, but it doesn't work. I'm getting no output. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can do it like this

```
$("#myselect option:selected").attr('custAttr');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[name=size]').attr("custAttr");
```

[.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0):

[attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1) should do the trick!

```
$('select[name=size]').attr('custAttr');
```